# Date Picker , how to restrict

Tags: datepicker

I am using CalendarXP 9.0 Calendar, In this how to restrict user to select only last day of the month.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with that tool, but it sounds like the functionality you essentially want is a month picker as opposed to a date picker.  They seem to have some drop-down based samples as well as a "whole month" selection option in [their demos](http://www.calendarxp.net/tt_pop.shtml).  What you want may be in there somewhere.

Basically, the approach you may end up taking would be to allow the user to select only a particular month (not even show them dates), or to allow them to select anything but set the date to the end of the month programmatically.

Comment: I have to show the dates but restrict to select only the end date of a month.